# linux tool for real time file replication between servers

Tags: replication, realtime

I have a web application. It is database and file driven (database is postgresql, users upload and create files)... I would like to balance the load between two+ servers, and that means not only database replication (which I can achieve with tools like Slony), but *also* real-time file replication.

The file replication is necessary because a user could log in in a first server, log out, 
then log in in the other server (because of the balancing), and his files should be there.
I don't really need to duplicte the whole drive, just a group of folders.

Also because if one server fails, I would like to have the other one with a full set of all data & files.

Is there any tool available on linux that automates reliable file replication, like the way Slony does for databases ?

Is DRBD a recommended solution ?

Comment: Would mounting a network drive (NFS share) work for you? If not, why not?

Comment: maybe... i´m looking for the simplest of solutions, yet scalable and efficient : )

Answer (score 2):

We use [Gluster](http://www.gluster.org/) for this, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

What is needed is a bidirectional filesystem (or folders) syncing. Search for Unison or DirSync Pro and give them a try